# Specify urls not to affect wih @-moz-document in stylish

Tags: css, stylish

With stylish you can specify a domains using `@-moz-document url-prefix(http://)` for example.

This applies to all URLs. Is there a way to specify which URLs you *don't* want the style to affect? This means you could have a global stylesheet that effects everything except specified URLs where there is another stylesheet you want to use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can get tricky but it can be done.
From the the Stylish documentation: ["Applying styles to specific sites"](https://github.com/JasonBarnabe/stylish/wiki/Applying-styles-to-specific-sites):

```js
@-moz-document regexp('(?!http://www\.example\.com).*') {
    /* CSS rules here.*/
}
```

Will activate for all URLs except those that start with `http://www.example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

my solution

```
@-moz-document regexp("^((?!(domain1\.com|domain2\.fr)).)*")
{
   ...YOUR CSS...
}
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue